# Give full citation when using crossref in biblatex windycity style

Tags: biblatex

I'm citing several chapters from a collection as well as the collection as a whole. In the notes, I want the first mention of the collection to give the full citation and any subsequent citations to give an abbreviated version of the collection. To achieve this, I am using the `crossref` field. In the bibliography, however, I want each chapter to give the entire citation. This can be normally be achieved by setting the option `mincrossrefs` to a high number, this workaround does not work when the collection itself is also cited. Is there a way to always give the full citation in the bibliography for child entries in the bibliography?

I am using the `windycity` style, but I believe this is an issue for all biblatex styles. `biblatex-chicago` has an option `longcrossref` that can be set to `bib` in order to achieve what I want, but I cannot use that package for other reasons (because I need to mix a notes-based style in my citations with an authordate style in my bibliography)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity,sorting=nyt,mincrossrefs=25]{biblatex}
\bibliography{windycity}
\begin{document}
\cites{lippincott1968}{keating1968}{angle1968}
\printbibliography[env=reflist]
\end{document}
```

The bibfile `windycity.bib` can be found in CTAN in the `doc` directory of `windycity`.

Comment: Is there any chance you can share the three example entries from `windycity.bib` with us, so we can test our solutions properly?

Comment: `windycity.bib` should be part of your tex distribution in the same way that `biblatex-examples.bib` is provided.

Comment: Hrmpf. Not on MikTeX. I shall get it from CTAN.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was provided by texlive so I assumed it was standard. I can provide my own examples later if it's still needed

Comment: I'm surprised the file is found in TeX live, from what I can see it lives in the `doc` tree and I thought that wasn't searched. No need to make up your own stuff, a short note in the question that `windycity.bib` is on CTAN for those who might not have it might be nice, but really this is more of a MikTeX packaging issue (which sometimes does not ship the documentation sources for some reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windycity` checks for the presence of the `crossref` field in order to decide whether or not to show a full citation.

So one simple way out would be to just delete the `crossref` field in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{windycity.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{crossref}}

\begin{document}
\cites{lippincott1968}{keating1968}{angle1968}
\printbibliography[env=reflist]
\end{document}
```

[image: Angle, Paul M., ed. 1968. Prairie State: Impressions of Illinois, 1673–1967, by Travelers and Other Observers. Chicago: University of Chicago Press.//Keating, William H. 1968. “Fort Dearborn and Chicago.” In Prairie State: Impressions of Illinois, 1673–1967, by Travelers and Other Observers, edited by Paul M. Angle, 84–87. Chicago: University of Chicago Press.//Lippincott, Sara Clarke. 1968. “Chicago.” In Prairie State: Impressions of Illinois, 1673–1967, by Travelers and Other Observers, edited by Paul M. Angle, 362–70. Chicago: University of Chicago Press.]

---

Alternatively, you can redefine the relevant bibmacro (at the beginning of the bibliography) to just skip all the tests for `crossref` and print the full data

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{windycity.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewbibmacro*{crossref+incollections}{%
    \usebibmacro{incollections}}}

\begin{document}
\cites{lippincott1968}{keating1968}{angle1968}
\printbibliography[env=reflist]
\end{document}
```